# what would be a concept in which "marriage" is one of its instances?

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to refer to a marriage but I've used the word too much already in my paragraph so I need to find another word which I could use in a sentence like:

"I had the pleasure to attend to the -------"

In Spanish, I could say something like "tuve el placer the estar presente para tan feliz ocasión¨ but that´s really hard to translate with a dictionary. Many things could constitute a ¨feliz ocasión" (~ happy occurrence), but it's clear from the context I'm referring to the marriage.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: Some clarification that I wrote below.

Imagine we are discussing the concept of "tragedy". Many things can be an instance of a tragedy, for example death, a certain illness, a certain outcome of some situation, they all can be referred to as "tragedy" with the appropriate context. I'm looking for the same thing for marriage, something in which marriage is one of the possibilities

Comment: Perhaps, if you alter the sentence a bit you can use "red-letter day"? [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/red-letter+day)

Comment: [*Nuptials*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nuptial?q=nuptials#nuptial__5) is one word. [More](http://thesaurus.com/browse/marriage), although not all are suitable.

Comment: Your "clarification" is anything but, I'm afraid. Perhaps you could rewrite the question? It seems difficult to equate *marriage* and *tragedy* (in most cases, anyway).

Comment: People do say "happy occasion" in this context (it sounds better than happy occurrence); I've even heard "blessed event" though I usually hear that more to describe the birth of a child.

Comment: Are you looking for a single word that means "a joyful event"?

Comment: "I had the pleasure of" seeing James and Joan joined in matrimonial bliss. Holy matrimony also works, as does Connubial: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/connubial

Comment: Your revised question seems less answerable than the original :'the name of a set containing this member' could have many answers. *Sacrament, celebration, party, occasion, service*? Also, are you clear on the distinction between *marriage* and *wedding*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supplementing the answer from @JeffSahol, if you mean you attended the marriage ceremony, you could say:

> I had the pleasure of attending the wedding of X & Y

---

**Addendum**, following clarified question

Even though I don't speak Spanish, I can see that the English translation of ¨feliz ocasión" would be "happy occasion" (not "occurrence" as you have written), and before noticing the translation point, I was already going to suggest that the expression **happy occasion** can be used to refer to many 'happy' events, such as weddings, birthdays, retirement, new job, or any other celebration.

Answer (score 1):

If it is clear from the context just what kind of ***service*** or ***ceremony*** you mean, then either of those words will work. But you would attend, not attend to, a marriage/ceremony/service.

Comment: mmm, I see. Thanks but I ruined it with my example. I actually didn't attend to it. Imagine we are discussing the concept of "tragedy". Many things can be an instance of a tragedy, for example death, a certain illness, a certain outsome of some situation, they all can be referred to as "tragedy" with the appropiate context. I'm looking for the same thing for marriage, something in which marriage is one of the possibilities. Do you now what I mean?

Comment: In that case, you could use a direct translation of the Spanish: "happy/joyous occasion/event".

Answer (score 0):

So you need to list the other types of occasion of which marriage is one instance. Do you mean to list 'happy occasions' in general, or the bonding of two people in various ways?

If the latter, you could say 'wedding' or 'union' or 'combination' or 'fusion' or 'joining together' or 'conjugation' or any number of similar words.

And just as an aside, your use of 'attend to' is not clear. To 'attend to' something means 'to deal with it'. But I think what you want to say is that you were present at the event, in which case you simply 'attend the wedding'.